# I am changing React Classes to React Hooks and getting error on setting state on onChange() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am changing my `ReactJs` code from Classes to React Hooks and getting error on setting state on `onChange()` function.
Both old and new code is mentioned below. Issue is only at `onChange()` method.

Main purpose of `onChange()` method is to get the values and set the state. So, on pressing add button it saves to database.

Thanks in advance for helping me to solve the issue.

**New Code**

```js
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
        import { Form } from "../Layout";
        import axios from "axios";
        import { store as notifications } from "react-notifications-component";
        import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
        import cellEditFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-editor";

        const Topping = () => {
          const [toppings, setToppings] = useState([]);
          const [topping, setTopping] = useState("");
          const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);

          const onChange=(e)=> {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setToppings({toppings, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
            //console.log("toppings", toppings);
          }
          useEffect(() => {
            getTopping();
          }, []);

          const getTopping = () => {
            axios
              .get("/topping/")
              .then(res => {
                setToppings(res.data);
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          };

          const addToppingAction = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const pizza = {
              name: topping,
              price: price
            };
            axios
              .post("/topping/add", pizza)
              .then(res => {
                notifications.addNotification({
                  message: res.data.topping,
                  type: "success",
                  insert: "top",
                  container: "bottom-right",
                  dismiss: {
                    duration: 2000
                  }
                });
                getTopping();
                setTopping("");
                setPrice(0);
              })
              .catch(err =>
                notifications.addNotification({
                  message: err.data,
                  type: "danger",
                  insert: "top",
                  container: "bottom-right",
                  dismiss: {
                    duration: 2000
                  }
                })
              );
          };
          function handleDelete(topping) {
            if (window.confirm("Delete Topping?" + topping.name)) {
              axios
                .get("/topping/delete/" + topping._id)
                .then(res => {
                  notifications.addNotification({
                    message: res.data,
                    type: "success",
                    insert: "top",
                    container: "bottom-right",
                    dismiss: {
                      duration: 5000
                    }
                  });
                  this.getTopping();
                })
                .catch(err => {});
            } else {
              notifications.addNotification({
                message: "action Cancelled",
                type: "danger",
                insert: "top",
                container: "bottom-right",
                dismiss: {
                  duration: 5000
                }
              });
            }
          }
          const columns = [
            { dataField: "_id", text: "ID", hidden: true },
            { dataField: "name", text: "Toppings" },
            { dataField: "price", text: "price" },
            {
              dataField: "databasePkey",
              text: "Remove",
              editable: false,
              formatter: (cellContent, sizes) => {
                return (
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(sizes)}
                  >
                    x
                  </button>
                );
              }
            }
          ];
          const cellEditProps = {
            mode: "click",
            blurToSave: true,
            beforeSaveCell(oldValue, newValue, row, column, done) {
              if (window.confirm("Apply Changes?")) {
                axios
                  .post("/topping/update/" + row._id, row)
                  .then(res => {
                    notifications.addNotification({
                      message: res.data,
                      type: "success",
                      insert: "top",
                      container: "bottom-right",
                      dismiss: {
                        duration: 5000
                      }
                    });
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    notifications.addNotification({
                      message: "Update Error",
                      type: "danger",
                      insert: "top",
                      container: "bottom-right",
                      dismiss: {
                        duration: 5000
                      }
                    });
                  });
                done(); // contine to save the changes
              } else {
                notifications.addNotification({
                  message: "action Cancelled",
                  type: "danger",
                  insert: "top",
                  container: "bottom-right",
                  dismiss: {
                    duration: 5000
                  }
                });
                done(false); // reject the changes
              }
              return { async: true };
            }
          };
          console.log("toppings", toppings);
          return (
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12 col-md-4">
                <h5>Add Topping</h5>
                <Form onSubmit={addToppingAction} className="pb-4">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="topping">
                      Topping
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="topping"
                      value={topping}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      placeholder="Topping"
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="price">
                      Price
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      step="0.1"
                      name="price"
                      value={price}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      placeholder="Price"
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
                    Add Toppings
                  </button>
                </Form>
              </div>
              <div className="col-12 col-md-8">
                <h5>Click to edit Topping</h5>
                {/* <BootstrapTable
                  keyField="_id"
                  data={toppings}
                  columns={columns}
                  cellEdit={cellEditFactory(cellEditProps)}
                />*/}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        };

        export default Topping;
```

**The OLD Code**

```js
     class Topping extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.addToppingAction = this.addToppingAction.bind(this);
         this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
         this.state = {
           toppings: [],
           topping: "",
           price: 0
         };
       }

       onChange = e => {
         this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
       };

       componentDidMount() {
         this.getTopping();
       }

       getTopping() {
         axios
           .get("/topping/")
           .then(res => {
             this.setState({
               toppings: res.data
             });
           })
           .catch(err => console.log(err));
       }

       addToppingAction(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         const pizza = {
           name: this.state.topping,
           price: this.state.price
         };
         axios
           .post("/topping/add", pizza)
           .then(res => {
             notifications.addNotification({
               message: res.data.topping,
               type: "success",
               insert: "top",
               container: "bottom-right",
               dismiss: {
                 duration: 2000
               }
             });
             this.getTopping();
             this.setState({ topping: "", price: 0 });
           })
           .catch(err =>
             notifications.addNotification({
               message: err.data,
               type: "danger",
               insert: "top",
               container: "bottom-right",
               dismiss: {
                 duration: 2000
               }
             })
           );
       }
       handleDelete(topping) {
         if (window.confirm("Delete Topping?" + topping.name)) {
           axios
             .get("/topping/delete/" + topping._id)
             .then(res => {
               notifications.addNotification({
                 message: res.data,
                 type: "success",
                 insert: "top",
                 container: "bottom-right",
                 dismiss: {
                   duration: 5000
                 }
               });
               this.getTopping();
             })
             .catch(err => {});
         } else {
           notifications.addNotification({
             message: "action Cancelled",
             type: "danger",
             insert: "top",
             container: "bottom-right",
             dismiss: {
               duration: 5000
             }
           });
         }
       }
       render() {
         const { topping, toppings, price } = this.state;
         const columns = [
           { dataField: "_id", text: "ID", hidden: true },
           { dataField: "name", text: "Toppings" },
           { dataField: "price", text: "price" },
           {
             dataField: "databasePkey",
             text: "Remove",
             editable: false,
             formatter: (cellContent, sizes) => {
               return (
                 <button
                   className="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                   onClick={() => this.handleDelete(sizes)}
                 >
                   x
                 </button>
               );
             }
           }
         ];
         const cellEditProps = {
           mode: "click",
           blurToSave: true,
           beforeSaveCell(oldValue, newValue, row, column, done) {
             if (window.confirm("Apply Changes?")) {
               axios
                 .post("/topping/update/" + row._id, row)
                 .then(res => {
                   notifications.addNotification({
                     message: res.data,
                     type: "success",
                     insert: "top",
                     container: "bottom-right",
                     dismiss: {
                       duration: 5000
                     }
                   });
                 })
                 .catch(err => {
                   console.log(err);
                   notifications.addNotification({
                     message: "Update Error",
                     type: "danger",
                     insert: "top",
                     container: "bottom-right",
                     dismiss: {
                       duration: 5000
                     }
                   });
                 });
               done();  contine to save the changes
             } else {
               notifications.addNotification({
                 message: "action Cancelled",
                 type: "danger",
                 insert: "top",
                 container: "bottom-right",
                 dismiss: {
                   duration: 5000
                 }
               });
               done(false);  reject the changes
             }
             return { async: true };
           }
         };
         return (
           <div className="row">
             <div className="col-12 col-md-4">
               <h5>Add Topping</h5>
               <Form onSubmit={this.addToppingAction} className="pb-4">
                 <div className="form-group">
                   <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="topping">
                     Topping
                   </label>
                   <input
                     type="text"
                     name="topping"
                     value={topping}
                     onChange={this.onChange}
                     placeholder="Topping"
                     className="form-control"
                   />
                 </div>
                 <div className="form-group">
                   <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="price">
                     Price
                   </label>
                   <input
                     type="number"
                     step="0.1"
                     name="price"
                     value={price}
                     onChange={this.onChange}
                     placeholder="Price"
                     className="form-control"
                   />
                 </div>

                 <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
                   Add Toppings
                 </button>
               </Form>
             </div>
             <div className="col-12 col-md-8">
               <h5>Click to edit Topping</h5>
               <BootstrapTable
                 keyField="_id"
                 data={toppings}
                 columns={columns}
                 cellEdit={cellEditFactory(cellEditProps)}
               />
             </div>
           </div>
         );
       }
     }

     export default Topping;
```

Comment: @A Mobin what's the error that you are getting

Comment: when I type into field but it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you should call setToppings with array parameter as the initial value 
and inside on change you call it with object

```
const onChange=(e)=> {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  if (name === 'toppings') {
    setToppings(e.target.value);
  }
  if (name === 'price') {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But what will be the fix of it?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array as initial value and updating the state with an object. I don't think this works.

Also you should use spread operator to "insert" the previous values in the new object :

```js
setToppings({...toppings, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```